# htaccess redirect issue, not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/commerce/ProductDetails.aspx\?mName=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)&source=List$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This looks like it should work great, but it doesn't actually do any redirecting.

I've also tried without escaping the question mark.

I am using this with a magento installation.  Mod rewrite is installed and working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure .htaccess is enabled and Rewrite Engine is enabled then try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mName=([^&]+)&source=List$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^commerce/ProductDetails\.aspx$ /%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Remember RewriteRule starts matching after first slash `/` and it doesn't match query string, you will need RewriteCont to match query string.

Comment: That works great.  One last question, would it be possible to make the resulting url be all lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "working", but did you forget the `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: No I didn't forget that part, sorry.  Basically I should be able to goto my site and it redirect accordingly.  For example.  http://domain.com/commerce/ProductDetails.aspx?mName=BC18&source=List should redirect to /BC18